# Update textview inside Widget from App activity in Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a widget which contains on TextView. From MainaActivity I am trying to update widget data as more data is added from main activity I want widget to refresh

```
class TodoWidget : AppWidgetProvider
{
..............

    private void SetTextViewText(RemoteViews widgetView)
    {
       // widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetMedium, new TodoDBR().GetAllRecordsForWidget());
        widgetView.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetSmall, new TodoDBR().GetAllRecordsForWidget());
    }
```

In Main activity, after adding data I am trying to call method to update widgets but it is not working

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(this.Context);
        var manager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(this.Context);
        var componentName = new ComponentName(Context.PackageName, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(TodoWidget)).Name);

        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.GetAppWidgetIds(componentName);
            appWidgetManager.NotifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, Resource.Layout.TodoWidget);
```

It is not updating my widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If have found answer my self just incase anyone else have same issue here is solution

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(Context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.TodoWidget);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(this.Context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(TodoWidget)).Name);
        remoteViews.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetSmall, new TodoDBR().GetAllRecordsForWidget());
        AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(this.Context).UpdateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't vote, but thank you - after 4 years. Finally it's working for me.
For someone too, calling update widget from main or service:

**CALL UPDATE: any place, service timer or MainActivity etc.:**

```
public void updateWidgets()
{
    Intent brIntent = new Intent(AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetUpdate);
    SendBroadcast(brIntent);
}
```

**RECIVE UPDATE: WidgetFile.cs:**

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(Context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.**TodoWidget**);
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(**TodoWidget**)));
    remoteViews.SetTextViewText(Resource.Id.widgetSmall, "Hello world");
    AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(this.Context).UpdateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
}
```

and next thing is .SetAction()